# Levi decomposition of connected Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a connected (**not necessarily simply-connected**) Lie group (which is not necessarily linear, not necessarily algebraic), and $\mathfrak{g}$ be its Lie algebra.

It is known that the Levi decomposition of its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ splits, i.e.
$$
\mathfrak{g} \cong \mathfrak{r} \rtimes \mathfrak{s}
$$
where $\mathfrak{r}$ is a radical of $\mathfrak{g}$ (maximal solvable ideal), and $\mathfrak{s}$ a semisimple Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$.

1. Does this extend to a parallel statement in $G$? That means, is it true that
   $$
   G \cong R \rtimes S
   $$
   where $R$ is the radical (maximal connected normal solvable Lie subgroup) of $G$ and $S$ some semisimple Lie subgroup of $G$? If yes, how can we see it directly from the Lie algebra statement? (My main problem is, I'm not sure how $\exp$ interacts with $\rtimes$.)

(I know for sure that, with $R$ being the radical of $G$, $G/R$ is semisimple. The main issue lies in the **split** property of $1 \to R \to G \to G/R \to 1$).

*This must be a very basic question, but I'm not familiar enough with the path between Lie groups and Lie algebra to trust my intuition...*

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Levi-Mal%27tsev_decomposition).

Comment: Also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67939/is-there-a-levi-decomposition-for-lie-group-and-algebraic-group)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The link pointed by @DietrichBurde has the quality of *simply-connected* imposed on $G$, while the (most useful answer, by Dietrich) in the MO link pointed by Callum, while quoting the theorem by Mostow, imposes a quality of *algebraic* on $G$. I am wondering if the decomposition still holds after all these are removed, and if so, why. Intuition is yes but I don't trust my intuition at all.

Comment: See Theorem $3.18.13$ in Varadarajan's book on Lie groups, Lie algebras and their representations for the Levi decomposition and the discussion about simply connected there.